# How can I handle onchange event for multiple select elements from map items

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a couple of select elements that are contained in every returned map item. When I try to change the value/option of one select element all the other select elements options change according to the option I select for one and this value is stored in a state and I don't want that. I want all the other select elements to change only when I select an option from them. I Have been battling to achieve this and it seems I can't really get the hang of it considering I just started learning ReactJs. I could really use some help. Below is my code snippet. Thanks

```
import React ,{useContext, useState} from 'react';
import StripeCheckout from 'react-stripe-checkout';
import {GlobalContext} from '../context/GlobalState';

const Cart = () => {
    const [options, setOptions] = useState(1);

    const {cart, removeItem, clearCart} = useContext(GlobalContext);
    const itemCount = cart.length > 1? ' items': ' item';
    const total = cart.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.price * options, 0);
    const handleToken = (token, address)=>{
    console.log(token, address)
}
    return (
        <div style={{fontFamily: "'Montserrat', 'sans-serif'"}} 
        className="relative px-20 ">
        <div className="relative block float-right mb-4">
            <span className="font-bold">{cart.length}{itemCount} in cart  
            </span>
            <button type="button" className="bg-gray-400 px-4 py-2" onClick= 
         {()=>{clearCart()}}>X Clear</button>
        </div>
        <div className="clear-float"></div>
        <table className="min-w-full table-auto mb-20">
          <thead className="justify-between">
              <tr className="bg-gray-800 text-gray-300">
                  <th className="px-16 py-4 text-left">Item</th>
                  <th className="px-12 py-4">Quantity</th>
                  <th className="px-12 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Unit 
                  Price</th>
                  <th className="px-12 py-4">Subtotal</th>
                  <th className="px-12 py-4">Action</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="bg-gray-200">
              {cart.length > 0?
            cart.map(cartItem =>(
              <tr key={cartItem.id} class="bg-white border-4 border-gray-200 
              ">
                  <td className="py-8 h-full inline-block grid grid-cols-2 
           gap-0">
                      <span className="w-full text-center">
                          <img className="h-48 w-auto text-center " src= 
       {cartItem.image}/>
                      </span>
                       <span className="w-full text-left">
                       {(<span className="block text-base text-left font- 
       semibold">{cartItem.title}</span>)
                     }
                      <span className="text-sm text-left"> 
                       {cartItem.description}</span>
                      </span> 
                  </td>
                  <td className="text-center py-8">
                  
                   <select  onChange={(e)=>setOptions(e.target.value)}>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                  </select> 
                  </td>
                  <td className="text-center py-8">{cartItem.price}</td>
                    <td className="text-center py-8">{options * 
                     cartItem.price.toFixed(2)}</td>
                    <td className="text-center"><button type="button" 
                   className="bg-gray-200 px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-300" 
                   onClick={()=>removeItem(cartItem.id)}><span className="fa 
                   fa-trash"></span> Remove</button></td>
              </tr>
           )):(<tr><td colSpan={5}><h1 className="bg-white text-xl text-gray- 
               500  font-semibold text-center pt-8"> No items in cart!</h1> 
            </td> 
                 </tr>)}
               <tr >
                    <td colSpan={5} className="bg-white  py-4 text-right">
                    <span className="inline-block px-2 text-xl 
                        font-extrabold">$ {total.toFixed(2)}</span>
                    <span className="ml-6 inline-block  bg-green-400 
                      hover:bg-green-300 font-semibold">
                        <StripeCheckout
                        stripeKey=""
                        name={cart.title}
                        amount={total.toFixed(2) * 100}
                        token={handleToken}
                        />
                    </span>
                    </td>
             </tr>              
          </tbody>
        </table>


 
       </div>
         )
   }
export default Cart;
```

Comment: Can you post the code  which you loop which has `map`.

Comment: okay....a moment lemme post the entire code from the component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the value of each `select` separately

Example

```
const [options, setOptions] = useState({});
```

Your `map` will look something like this

```
myArray.map((element, i) => {
       return <select name={`select-${i}`} value={options[`select-${i}`]} onChange={(e)=>setOptions({...options, [`select-${i}`]: e.target.value)}>

           <option>...</option>
       </select>
   })
```

This way each `select` value is stored separatly.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot but the issue now is that the first option doesn't get selected automatically except i select one other option before selecting it despite  including the html selected attribute plus how can I update the total variable in the part of options? It returns NaN....been trying all day. Thanks @kiranvj

Comment: @ericDonald Try this to initially select first option value={options[`\`select-${i}`\`] || '1' }  This will work as long as the value of first option is 1. To get the total value your can use `Object.values(options).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @kiranvj

Comment: Thanks for your reply @kiranvj. From your code i wrote this to get the total cost of items but it's giving me exponential figures sort of. ```const totalOpts = Object.values(options).reduce((a,b) => a + parseInt(b), 0);
    const total = cart.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.price * totalOpts, 0)``` Getting the sum of the options and adding to the sum of the subtotal cost automatically multiplies even if i select 1 for each item. I tried to get just the sum of the subtotal cost of the items but i just couldn't get it right cos it's in a map function. I just hope you understand my explanation.

Comment: @ericDonald I didnt get it fully, maybe you can create a new question for that.